# Не понимаю почему выводятся только нули

Tags: c++, функции, вывод

Дан массив из N натуральных чисел и цифра K. Требуется определить, сколько чисел массива содержат цифру K.

```
using namespace std;
int digitCounter(int n, int v, int k) {
  int a = 0, m = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    while (v != 0) {
      a = v % 10;
      v = v / 10;
      if (a == k) {
        m++;
      }
    }
  }
  return m;
}

int main() {
  int arr[100], n, k, result ;
  cin >> n;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cin >> arr[i];
  cin >> k;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    result = digitCounter(n, arr[i], k);
  }

  cout << result;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну, как минимум, у вас выводится только одно значение, для `i == n-1`... А вообще что-то вы не то считаете, а количество вхождений k в конкретное число.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, как минимум, у вас выводится только одно значение, для `i == n-1`... А вообще что-то вы не то считаете, а? похоже, количество вхождений `k` в конкретное число, и тут же его забываете...

Я бы делал так (защиты "от дурака" нет).

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int n;
  cin >> n;
  vector<int> a;
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
      int m;
      cin >> m;
      a.push_back(m);
  }
  int k, result = 0;
  cin >> k;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
      int m = a[i];
      while(m)
      {
          if (m%10 == k)
          {
              ++result;
              break;
          }
          m /= 10;
      }
  }
  cout << result;
}
```

А если бы `k` можно было вводить до массива — то и массив бы не потребовался.